# HBaseConfiguration don't read values that I setup in ${HBASE_HOME}/conf/hbase-site.xml

Tags: configuration, hadoop, hbase

${HBASE_HOME}/conf/hbase-site.xml have next values:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>hd1</value>
</property>
```

"hd1" hostname is setup in "/etc/hosts", pinging works...

With this simple Java programe:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;

public class TestConfigurator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        System.out.println("HBase quorum: " + conf.get("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost"));
    }
}
```

I get "localhost". HBase is setup in distributed mode, with one master and 2 region servers... And all conf files are synced, and I rebooted all servers multiple times.

Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either `${HBASE_HOME}/conf/hbase-site.xml` is not in the classpath or it is being overridden by some other `conf-site.xml` (Most likely the `conf-site.xml` that comes bundled with the HBase jar)

To fix it, you can add a HBase conf directory with your custom settings to your classpath, and then call your program with that classpath. e.g,

`java -cp <earlier classpath>:<your custom conf location> <your program>`

Comment: It was about conf-site.xml that is in hbase.jar. Just adding /etc/hbase/conf/ in classpath solves problem. Big thanks